# How to remove part of the URL and redirect using mod_rewrite in htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla

I would like to remove part of the url of my Joomla site and redirect to another url for example

www.example.com/xxx/yyy/zzz/FAQ

www.example.com/123/456/FAQ

to

www.example.com/FAQ

I'm very new to mod_rewrite in .htacesss

what RewriteRule can I write to achive this

thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in root/htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /xx/yy/zz/([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [NC,L,R]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /xx/yy/zz/$1 [NC,L]
```

And the same rule can be used to rewrite /123/456/faq to /123/456/FAq , just change the rewrite target and the pattern in first Rewritecond.

$1 is part of the regex in rewrite rule, its the part matched between (.+) ,it contains uri.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but what I actually need is turn "www.example.com/xxx/yyy/zzz/FAQ" into "www.example.com/FAQ.

I want to remove "/xxx/yyy/zzz" (which can be anything) so if possible I would like to find a way to remove any string between ".com/" and "/FAQ"

I think your answer is the opposite.

Comment: Thank you Starkeen, I think I found the solution and will post it soon :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, after I tried I finally got it working

this is my solution

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^.*/FAQ$ /FAQ [L,R=301]
```

by doing this I remove everything between the URL and FAQ

www.abc.com/SOMETHING/SOMETHING2/FAQ

and redirect the URL to

www.abc.com/FAQ

I also found a nice tool to test the mod_rewrite code
http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/